# Nextjs 13- Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Currently I'm trying to fetch response from my server component, nextjs 13, here's the code snippet----------------->

```js
import db from "../../../../utils/db";
import Product from "../../../../models/Product";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default async function GET(req, res){
  try {
    db.connectDb();
    const id = req.params.id;
    const size = req.searchParams.size;
    const style = req.searchParams.style;
    const product = await Product.findById(id).lean();
    let discount = product.subProducts[style].discount;
    let priceBefore = product.subProducts[style].sizes[size].price;
    let price = discount ? priceBefore - priceBefore / discount : priceBefore;
    db.disconnectDb();

    return NextResponse.json({
      _id: product._id,
      style: Number(style),
      name: product.name,
      description: product.description,
      slug: product.slug,
      sku: product.subProducts[style].sku,
      brand: product.brand,
      category: product.category,
      subCategories: product.subCategories,
      shipping: product.shipping,
      images: product.subProducts[style].images,
      color: product.subProducts[style].color,
      size: product.subProducts[style].sizes[size].size,
      price,
      priceBefore,
      quantity: product.subProducts[style].sizes[size].qty,
    });
    
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: error.message },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }

}
```

In my client component I have the handleClick button function to retur n the json data, here's my client component code snippet--------------------->

```js
 async function handleClick() {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/product/${product._id}?style=${product.style}&size=${dsize}`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    });
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  }
```

On my clg I can see the json from the server, here's a snapshot------------------------->

[image]

But on the client component, once I clg the data, I get the error uncaught in promise, someone please what's happening, I'm using nextjs as my backend framework and reactjs as the frontend framework..

The error from my clg below----------->
[image]

[image]

[image]

App component tree on server side
[image]

Comment: Log what the client component is actually receiving instead of the expected JSON.  (It'll be a server error page formatted in HTML, which may help indicate the underlying problem.) (Which is probably a CORS-related error.)

Comment: @DanielBeck the error I'm getting I've updated it with a snapshot

Comment: As you can see, that is indeed an HTML page instead of the JSON you were expecting.  (It'll be easier to read if you log it before trying to call `.json()` on it.)  It looks like the initializer for your react app -- you may have misconfigured your server to treat that URL as a react route instead of allowing the request to go through to the server.

Comment: @DanielBeck Okay so without json, what I get I updated it as an image above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention "client component" and "server component", I'm assuming you are using Next.js `app` router. In which case, you made a mistake in your router handler:

```
export default async function GET(req) {}
```

This is incorrect.

The correct route handler format is:

```
export async function GET(req) {}
```

Notice that it's not a default export.

---

The error you are getting is an HTML page from Next.js saying that the route doesn't exist. Because its looking for a named export `GET` which it cannot find.

Refer for more details: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#convention

Comment: Take a look at the server component tree in the app folder, I'm actually rendering a page above----------------->

Comment: @Deezy Have you made the change suggested in my answer?

Comment: Yes! I followed through wah you said, I got two errors, the default export is not a react component and Uncaught in promise, the error earlier

Comment: @Deezy Do you have a `pages` directory anywhere?

Comment: I have an app directory-->api---->product folder--->[id]----->page.js, I have uploaded the file tree cause I'm getting the response from the api directory.....

Comment: I don't have pages directory anywhere...

Comment: Next Js 13 the latest version disregarded pages directory upon installation, they moved it to the app directory

Comment: @Deezy Not true. `pages` router still work in Next.js latest version. If you instead have a `pages` directory along with `app` directory, I have seen the `pages` directory given higher precedence (might be fixed in latest Next.js version). Hence why I wanted to confirm if you have `pages` directory anywhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255519/discussion-between-robin-thomas-and-deezy).